When a certain range of values ​does not exist in the original data, how can it be displayed in the legend?
I tried to present some ranges of values not existing in my original data in the legend of output figure, but only the text showed up without color and size.
Here is my original data:
merged_data<-structure(list(Order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), latitude = c(43.2143, 43.3697, 
43.3909, 43.3926, 43.3961, 43.3978, 43.066, 43.2215, 43.368, 
43.435, 43.4434, 43.4623, 43.4895, 43.4856, 43.3738, 43.4761, 
43.5102, 43.5118, 43.5062, 43.4933), longitude = c(-4.479, -4.4804, 
-4.4606, -4.4484, -4.4241, -4.412, -4.1046, -4.1049, -4.1031, 
-4.0818, -4.021, -3.9502, -3.8184, -3.7798, -3.7279, -3.7147, 
-3.5971, -3.5849, -3.5585, -3.5177), median_mafruit = c(2.73, 
1.095, 1.115, 2.73, 0.527, 0.527, 0.962, 1.039, 1.039, 2.73, 
2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 0.544, 2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 0.478, 2.73)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Order = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), median_mafruit = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

As you can see, there are no values in the range of [1.5, 2), [2, 2.5), [3, 3.5), [3.5, 4].
I plot the figure with the code below:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

merged_data_sf <- st_as_sf(merged_data, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

# Define color and size breaks and values
color_breaks <- c(0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0)
colors <- c("#E31A1C", "#FF7F00", "#FDBF6F", "#E9E4A6", "#A4D4A9", "#B2DF8A", "#33A02C", "#1F78B4")

size_breaks <- c(0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0)
sizes <- c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4)

merged_data_sf$median_mafruit_cut <- cut(
 merged_data_sf$median_mafruit,
 breaks = color_breaks,
 include.lowest = TRUE,
 right = FALSE
)

levels_cut <- levels(merged_data_sf$median_mafruit_cut)

p1 <- ggplot() +
 geom_sf(data = world, fill = "grey87", color = "white") + 
 geom_sf(
   data = merged_data_sf,
   aes(
     size = median_mafruit_cut,
     color = median_mafruit_cut
   ),
   alpha = 0.7
 ) +
 labs(
   x = "Longitude (°)",
   y = "Latitude (°)"
 ) +
 scale_color_manual(
   values = setNames(colors, levels_cut),
   breaks = levels_cut,
   drop = FALSE
 ) +
 scale_size_manual(
   values = setNames(sizes, levels_cut),
   breaks = levels_cut,
   drop = FALSE  # Ensure full range in legend
 ) +
 coord_sf(
   xlim = c(-5, -3),
   ylim = c(43, 44),
   expand = FALSE
 ) +
 guides(
   size = guide_legend(
     title = bquote("Yield (t·ha"^.(1)*")"),
     order = 1
   ),
   color = guide_legend(
     title = bquote("Yield (t·ha"^.(1)*")"),
     order = 1
   )
 )+
 theme_minimal() 

p1

And here is the figure I got:

As you can see, for some ranges, for example [1.5, 2), there are no color and no size. I assigned color #E9E4A6 and size 2 in advance, but it didn't work out in the legend.
Therefore, how should I adjust my code to present colors and sizes for all the ranges, even some ranges don't exist in my original data?
Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you in advance!!!

Include show.legend = TRUE in geom_sf() (the second one). Next time, try to make your example minimal by removing all code that is not necessary to reproduce your problem.
